# Is there a way for tar to check for new files not in an archive?

Tags: files, tar, update

Is there a way to for the tar command to check for new files that are not already in the archive, or those that have been deleted (for good measure)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `tar -d` to see if local filesystem files are different or missing.

To add new files, just use `tar -u` to add only files newer than the copy in the archive.

```
tar -cvf /tmp/backup.tar /home # adds all files
echo Hello > /home/newfile.txt
tar -uvf /tmp/backup.tar /home # adds only newfile.txt
rm /home/newfile.txt
tar -df /tmp/backup.tar /home # gives an error about newfile.txt missing
```